# Use AWS Role to authorize Lambda querying AWS datastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to write a Lambda function which will depend upon data stored in some AWS datastore (DynamoDB/Redshift/RDS). I had hoped that authorization for this could be handled by IAM - i.e. if I ran the Lambda function under a Role which was authorized to read the datastore, I would not need to provide credential details for access.

However, [this code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-deployment-pkg.html) (which is part of an example on "[Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)") still requires username and password.

Is it possible to use an IAM role to authorize Lambda to query an AWS datastore?

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on which datastore you decide to use. DynamoDB access is controlled by IAM since it is a proprietary Amazon service. RDS databases and ElastiCache all use the authorization scheme of the database engine you chose when you create an RDS server or ElastiCache cluster, which I believe in all cases is some form of username/password. Also Aurora uses a login and password just like MySQL, since it is MySQL compatible, and Redshift uses login/password just like PostgreSQL since it is PostgreSQL compatible.

I highly recommend you chose a data store based on your actual data storage requirements. Pick RDS if you need a relational OLTP database, Redshift if you need an OLAP database, ElastiCache if you need a Redis or Memcached cache, a third-party or self-managed NoSQL database like mLab/MongoDB, or use DynamoDB if a NoSQL database will work and DynamoDB fits your needs.

Comment: OK - so it sounds like any non-Dynamo system will require including username/password in the code itself (or some configuration file along with the code). Interesting - isn't that a security concern?

Ideally, we'd be using Elasticache, since the data in question is slow-changing, and immediate consistency is not a massive concern. That said, I've (anecdotally) heard that Elasticache is pretty expensive, which will also be a concern.

Comment: Look at it this way, if you give your EC2 server an IAM role that allows access to a database, then anyone that gets access to the EC2 server can also gain access to your database. How is that more secure than storing the database username/password credentials on the server? And note I'm not recommending storing those credentials in your code, as that is indeed a security concern. If you're really concerned about this, then look into using the AWS KMS service to store your credentials.

Comment: Also I'd skip the anecdotal info and go straight to the source. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/ ElastiCache might be a little more expensive than running Redis on an EC2 server manually, but it handles lots of management tasks for you. And it is definitely cheaper than running an RDBMS on RDS. You also might want to look at RedisLabs if price is a concern, but ElastiCache will generally be more secure since it runs entirely within your VPC.

Comment: I will add that DynamoDB is a great fit with AWS Lambda. You can use it without placing your Lambda functions within your VPC, which has several advantages. And you can use IAM roles for access like you are looking for. If you can work within the idiosyncrasies of DynamoDB then it great to use alongside AWS Lambda.

Comment: You can decrypt the credentials (username / password) with a KMS key and give the Lambda function the permission to decrypt using that key. On startup of the Lambda function you decrypt the credentials and then connect to the db.